# Linkedin contacts who have installed my app?

Tags: java, android, linkedin-api

I'm developing an android application and i have integrated Linkedin into my app for authentication by using this link
http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/android-linkedin-connectivity-code-sample/.

I want to know user's connections(friends/associates) in Linkedin who have installed my app i,e user's Linkedin connections who have downloaded my app.Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

I believe most of the time this task is done on the application side from scratch (It was called autodiscovery in our project).

So basically what you need is connection management for the User. Simplest possible solutions:

1. App based User connection management.

   In this case you need to have some distributed Key-Value store available to your Android application (Some Redis host for example).

   The simplest workflow in this case

   1. Populate key-value - like linkedIn_ID -> your_application_id on LinkedIn API authorisation.
   2. Find connected users for your Application, querying by connection LinkedIn_ID.
2. Server based User connection management

   The same thing, but introducing separate API on your server.

In both cases, take in consideration new connections, that might appear after some time.

Comment: Thanks this does answer my question.. but my doubt is do i have to do all these things in my database or does Linkedin too provide a method like facebook does for achieving this?

Comment: Can you give me a link to facebook API, that does that, maybe it was not in place, when we were implementing our solution.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/friends.. Please go through this link if i'm not wrong it gives user's friends who installed my app..

Comment: Thanks, this was not available, when we were writing our functionality:)